# run mocha test in vscode extensions api

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I am currently developing an VSCode extension. I've already made some tests in mocha and chai.

I'm trying to execute them directly with the recommend lines in package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
    "compile": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
```

But when I test this code in `tree.test.ts`:

```
import { convertPathToPosix } from "../../tree/src/path_manipulation";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("Test of path manipulations", () => {
  it("Convert a Windows path to Posix path", () => {
    const windowsPath = "C:\\repos\\vue-t\\tests\\views\\index\\home.vue";
    expect(convertPathToPosix(windowsPath)).to.be.eql(
      "C:/repos/vue-t/tests/views/index/home.vue"
    );
  });
  it("Convert a Posix path to Posix path", () => {
    const posixPath = "usr/bin/bash.rc";
    expect(convertPathToPosix(posixPath)).to.be.eql("usr/bin/bash.rc");
  });
});
```

I got the error:

```
ReferenceError: describe is not defined ...
```

Here the files structure:

```
src
 test
   runTest.ts
   suite
      -tree.test.ts
      -index.ts
 tree
   src
      -path_manipulation.ts
```

I understand that it misses something in the package.json or elsewhere to make mocha works but I don't know where and how.

Is there a way to run mocha test in the test environment of VSCode extensions api ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `tdd` is used in the mocha configuration (*suite/index.ts* file).

If yes, replace it with `bdd`.

```
const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'bdd'
});
```